# Cannot set a env var when using macos runner

Tags: github-actions

I'm attempting to use github action' macos runner since it has more memory. However, I'm having trouble setting a date.

I need a date of the form yyyymmdd e.g. 20220731. This code works fine on local:

```
export RUNDATEOSX=$(date -d "-2 days" +%Y%m%d)
[arch@e28c15002791 OSX-KVM]$ echo $RUNDATEOSX 
20220731
```

But on the macos runner:

Tried:

```
jobs:
  get-bq-data:
    runs-on: macos-11
    name: Get GA4 data from BQ
    steps:
      - name: Set env
        run: export RUNDATEOSX=$(date -d "-2 days" +%Y%m%d) >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: echo RUNDATEOSX
        run: echo $RUNDATEOSX
```

[image]

It's empty, $RUNDATEOSX is not there.

How can I set an env var on the mac-os runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first issue** may be that you generally don't need to use `export` with Github Actions.

To add or set variables to the `GITHUB_ENV`, according to the [Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable), you need to use the following syntax:

`echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

---

**Another issue** may be related to the macOs version you used locally to test the `date` command.

This command line`$(date -d "-2 days" +%Y%m%d)` also returned me the same error locally (using macos 12.4) as the `macos-latest` runner on Github:

```
date: illegal option -- d
usage: date [-jnRu] [-r seconds|file] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]]
            [-I[date | hours | minutes | seconds]]
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

However, using this other command line: **`$(date -j -v-2d +%Y%m%d)`**, I got the expected result.

---

Therefore, the workflow you should use to get what you want would look like below:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Set variable
      run: |
        RUNDATEOSX=$(date -j -v-2d +%Y%m%d)
        echo "RUNDATEOSX=$RUNDATEOSX" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Print variable
      run: |
        echo "RUNDATEOSX:" ${{ env.RUNDATEOSX }} # First option
        echo "RUNDATEOSX:" $RUNDATEOSX # Second option
```

*Note: Here are the [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester49.yml) and the [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7642843346?check_suite_focus=true) I used to check, if you want to have a look.*